# How to calculate $a^b$ (mod 10, 100 etc. ), where $a$ is not co-prime to $10$.

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to learn to find out the last digits for an arbitrary power ($b$) of arbitrary number ($a$) i.e. of $a^b$ where $a$ and $b$ both are natural numbers.

For last digit we shall solve $a^b \equiv x$ (mod $10$). For last two digits we shall solve $a^b \equiv x$ (mod $100$). For last three digits we shall solve $a^b \equiv x$ (mod $1000$) and so on.

I have considered a counterexample $6^{73}$(mod 10) and (mod $100$). I am facing the following problems.

1. $6$ is not co-prime to $10$, so we can not use Fermat's or Euler's or Carmichael's formula. So I am taking a system of linear congruence $6^{73} \equiv x$ (mod$5$) and $6^{73} \equiv y$ (mod$2$) and then I want to apply Chinese Remainder Theorem. I am getting $x = 1$ and $y = 0$. **Now I do not know how to use Chinese reminder Theorem. Please explain step by step.**
2. $100 = 2^2 \times 5^2$. Can I apply the relations $6^{73} \equiv 1$ (mod$5$) and $6^{73} \equiv 0$ (mod$2$) to find the last two digits? **How ?** Otherwise I have to solve $6^{73} \equiv x$ (mod$25$) and $6^{73} \equiv y$ (mod$4$), and then the same method will be used.

I am learning a few topics of number theory myself. Please sufficient resources for this problem. Is there any other method for solving such type of problems? *Can we find the first digit of this number in this way?*

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As $(6^{73},10)=2,$ start with  $$6^{73-1}\pmod{\frac{10}2}\text{ i.e.,} 6^{72}\pmod5$$

As $\displaystyle6\equiv1\pmod5, 6^r\equiv1$ where integer $r\ge0$(Here $r=72$)

Now use $\displaystyle a\equiv b\pmod m\implies a\cdot c\equiv b\cdot c\pmod{m\cdot c}$ where $a,b,m,c$ are integers

Here $c=6$

Comment: I was thinking you to come. Please discuss a little. So here $6^{72} \times 6 \equiv 6$ (mod 30), But I need for (mod 10).What to do?

Comment: @HopelessFool, So, $30$ divides $6^{73}-6,$ right? So will $10$ as $10|30$

Comment: Now what to do for 100?

Comment: @HopelessFool, what is the gcd$(6^{73},100)=d$? As the highest power of $2$ in $6$ is $1,$ so take out $6^d$ and start with $6^{73-d}$

Comment: Here digits are large in calculation. $d = 2^2 = 4$. I am getting $6^{69} \equiv 6^{9} \equiv 11$ (mod $25$). So $6^{73} \equiv 44$ (mod 100). Is it?

Comment: @HopelessFool, why not, we have $$6^{73}\equiv0\pmod 4\text{ and } 6^{73}\equiv44\pmod{25}\equiv19$$

Comment: I did not understand the last comment. Please improve the answer.

Comment: Using  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html,  from my last comment $a_1=0, a_2=19$   Can you take it from here